# Using rsync to rename files during copying with --files-from?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, rename

Using rsync, how can I rename files when copying with the --files-from argument? I have about 190,000 files, each of which need to be renamed when copying from source to destination. I plan to have the list of files in a text file to pass to the --files-from argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think `rsync` has any built-in renaming capability. The first workaround that comes to mind is that you could create a local mirror directory, with (renamed) symlinks to the actual data. Then you could use `rsync` on the mirror directory, adding the `-L` option ("transform symlink into referent file/dir"). You'd want to write a quick helper script to automate updating the mirrored structure, but it doesn't sound too scary.

Answer (score 3):

If your rename would consist of merely adding a suffix to the existing name, then you might be able to use the `--backup` and `--suffix` options to `rsync`.